# Get registry full path having partial path in powershell

Tags: powershell, key, registry

I have problems getting the full path of a registry key by having 98% of the path except the version.

What i tried and not working is :

`(Get-Item -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Maxon Cinema 4D R*").FullName` - this will work for file/folder path but not for registry .

`"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Maxon Cinema 4D R*"` using like this also is not working. I also tried a bunch of variations with get-item/get-childitem/full path/literalpath and didn't get anywhere.

`Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Maxon Cinema 4D R*" | Select-Object "Uninstallstring"`  - this will get the Object but i dont know how to get only the path and exclude "@{UninstallString=" from the string.

The result that i'm searching for is :
`"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Maxon Cinema 4D R25"` but the version can differ, can be 22 or 24 or something else. To be more specific, I'm trying to get the uninstallstring value of the Maxon Cinema 4d which i can find it if i can get the fullname of the registry key.

Comment: i solved the problem with `Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Maxon Cinema 4D R*"`           and this also worked for value :  `Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Maxon Cinema 4D R*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Uninstallstring" `

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ItemProperty` gives you more properties than just the 'UninstallString'.

```
$result = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Maxon Cinema 4D R*" | Select-Object PSPath, Uninstallstring
```

Now $result wil be either a single object, or an array of objects with two properties.

If you output that to console using `$result | Format-Table -AutoSize` you will see what is in it.

You can get the value of these properties simple enough like

```
$result[0].PSPath
$result[0].UninstallString
```